# How to get file names only from s3 bucket using Boto3

Tags: boto3

I am using the commands specified below:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')

page_iterator_1 = paginator.paginate(Bucket='Bucket-Name',Prefix=alh-source/', PaginationConfig={'PageSize':1})
page_iterator = page_iterator_1.search("Contents[?contains(Key,'.json')].Key")

for page in page_iterator:
    print(page)
```

The output is

```
alh-source/ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json
alh-source/ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_9.json
```

However, my output should only contain the file names, as shown below:

```
ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json
ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_9.json
```

Answer (score 1):

`alh-source/ALH_LXN_RESPONSE_10.json` is the S3 object key. S3 doesn't really have a concept of folders and filenames, it's all just a unique string that is used as the object key. If you want the portion after the final `/` you could do some simple string manipulation like:

```
print(page.split('/')[-1])
```